# How to get a proper error line number with $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Tags: powershell

Consider the following script

```
#requires -version 2.0

[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
)

$script:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
function PSScriptRoot { $MyInvocation.ScriptName | Split-Path }

function ThrowFunction($i)
{
    "ThrowFunction $i"
    $someNonExistingVariable
}

@(1, 2, 3) | ForEach-Object -Process { ThrowFunction $_ }
```

When we run it we get

```
C:\dev> .\MyScript.ps1
ThrowFunction 1
ForEach-Object : The variable '$someNonExistingVariable' cannot be retrieved because it has not      been set.
At C:\dev\MyScript.ps1:18 char:28
+ @(1, 2, 3) | ForEach-Object <<<<  -Process { ThrowFunction $_ }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (someNonExistingVariable:Token) [ForEach-Object],     RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :      VariableIsUndefined,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

As you see it reports the problem in line #18

But the actual problem is in the line #15

I found that if we change Line 8:

```
$script:ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
```

We get

```
C:\dev> .\MyScript.ps1
ThrowFunction 1
The variable '$someNonExistingVariable' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\dev\MyScript.ps1:15 char:29
+     $someNonExistingVariable <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (someNonExistingVariable:Token) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined

ThrowFunction 2
The variable '$someNonExistingVariable' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\dev\MyScript.ps1:15 char:29
+     $someNonExistingVariable <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (someNonExistingVariable:Token) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined

ThrowFunction 3
The variable '$someNonExistingVariable' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\dev\MyScript.ps1:15 char:29
+     $someNonExistingVariable <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (someNonExistingVariable:Token) [],     RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

And you see that now line 15 is reported as expected.

Now the question is how to get the proper line and have “Stop” behavior.

I tried many approaches and none of them worked for me.

I tried

```
trap { throw $_ }

trap { $_.InvocationInfo }

trap { Get-PSCallStack }
```

but none of them gets the proper line

Then I tried to switch

```
$script:ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
```

and found that as soon as I add any trap, the wrong line is being reported again.

So I am still looking for a working solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Keith Hill, I found a solution

The magic line is

```
trap { throw $Error[0] }
```

This script

```
#requires -version 2.0

[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
)

$script:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
function PSScriptRoot { $MyInvocation.ScriptName | Split-Path }

trap { throw $Error[0] }

function ThrowFunction($i)
{
    "ThrowFunction $i"
    $someNonExistingVariable
}

@(1, 2, 3) | ForEach-Object -Process { ThrowFunction $_ }
```

returns

```
C:\Dev> .\MyScript.ps1
ThrowFunction 1
The variable '$someNonExistingVariable' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\Dev\MyScript.ps1:17 char:29
+     $someNonExistingVariable <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (someNonExistingVariable:Token) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

Great!

Answer (score 4):

Even though you've set strictmode to Latest, the `$someNonExistingVariable` does not generate a terminating error. It just writes to the Error stream.  By setting ErrorActionPreference to `Stop`, you now have Foreach-Object converting the non-terminating error into a terminating error.  That is why the error indicates line 18 - the Foreach-Object cmdlet.

If you look in the $Error collection, assuming you Clear() it first, you would see two errors. The latest is in $Error[0] - this is the terminating error thrown by Foreach-Object.  $Error[1] is the non-terminating error written by the attempt to access an undefined variable.  It has the right line number - 15.

You can access the ScriptStackTrace like so:

```
PS C:\> $error[0].errorRecord.ScriptStackTrace
at ThrowFunction, C:\Users\hillr\ErrorLine.ps1: line 15
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\hillr\ErrorLine.ps1: line 18
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\hillr\ErrorLine.ps1: line 18
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith Hill. I applied your idea to provide an answer. BTW, I could not apply your solution because *ScriptStackTrace* does not exist in PowerShell 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can you Try {} Catch {} instead :

```
#requires -version 2.0

[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
)

$script:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
function PSScriptRoot { $MyInvocation.ScriptName | Split-Path }

function ThrowFunction($i)
{
    "ThrowFunction $i"
    Try {
        $someNonExistingVariable
    }
    Catch { # The variable $_ represents the error that is caught
    Write-Output $_
    }
}

@(1, 2, 3) | ForEach-Object -Process { ThrowFunction $_ }
```

And the resulting output gives the correct line number :

```
ThrowFunction 1
The variable '$someNonExistingVariable' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:16 char:9
+         $someNonExistingVariable
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (someNonExistingVariable:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined

ThrowFunction 2
The variable '$someNonExistingVariable' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:16 char:9
+         $someNonExistingVariable
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (someNonExistingVariable:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined

ThrowFunction 3
The variable '$someNonExistingVariable' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:16 char:9
+         $someNonExistingVariable
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (someNonExistingVariable:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

Comment: Yes, I could, but I'd prefer a solution which is working without knowing the problematic place beforehand. That is the solution that  I accepted - just a simple trap statement